# find the index of first occurrence of the Integer from the string using java

Tags: java, regex

I have the String `xxxxy 1/1/2` , I need to find out the  index of first occurrence of Integer from the string using java . The output will be First "1"th index. I need regex for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use regex but if you must use it :

```
    String s = "xxxxy 1/1/2";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\D*(\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.start(1));
```

output :6

Answer (score 5):

No need to use a regex. Convert your String to a char array, loop on it and use [Character#isDigit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

Comment: If the first value is 15. How to get the whole value

Comment: @newuser: Not sure whether OP wants the digit or the whole number...

Comment: @newuser OP wants to find index of first occurrence of integer, not its value.

Comment: The OP seems to want the first occurence of Integer. If the OP wants to have the full number, it is possible to multiply by 10 for each digit encountered.

Comment: Ok i understand both of your comment. But i want to know about that. So only i ask you

Answer (score 2):

```
int pos = s.replaceFirst("^(\\D+).*$", "$1").length();
```

Keeps the non-digits `\\D`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also omit using regexps with this code although it's more for-fun-solution than clean and effective.

```
for(String b : "abc123cde".split("[a-z]")) {        
    try {
        Integer result = Integer.parseInt(b);
        if(result != null) {
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
         //nevermind
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get index from string with this function:

```
function GetIndex (strValue) {
var notDigRegExp = /^\D+/; 
var digRegExp = /^\d+/;
strValue = strValue.replace(notDigRegExp, "");
var matches = strValue.match(digRegExp);
return matches[0];
};
```